# Select query that outputs counts of rows that are within a certain time period

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My question is little bit more complicated than what the title implies but here it is:

I have a table with punch data formatted like this:

```
name time_in              time_out             location
1    2018-05-31 10:09:00  2018-05-31 16:06:00  1
3    2018-05-31 10:12:00  2018-05-31 17:03:00  1
```

I would like a select query that returns the total time in hours of people that are working during a 15min time frame for each location. Here is an example output for the two rows given:

```
time                 labor_hours  location
2018-05-31 10:00:00  .15          1
2018-05-31 10:15:00  .50          1
2018-05-31 10:30:00  .50          1
2018-05-31 10:45:00  .50          1
2018-05-31 11:00:00  .50          1
...
2018-05-31 15:45:00  .50          1
2018-05-31 16:00:00  .35          1
2018-05-31 16:15:00  .25          1
2018-05-31 16:30:00  .25          1
2018-05-31 16:45:00  .25          1
2018-05-31 17:00:00  .10          1
```

Labor hours is total hours worked during a 15min time period in hours. So for example, the first row was calculated by looking at the first two rows and seeing that from 10:00:00 - 10:15:00 employee 1 and 2 worked for a total of 9 minutes. Since it's in hours 9/60 = .15.

I'm new to sql so I'm pretty lost on how to start with this.

Comment: So you want to round up the minutes to a 15 minute mark. IOW if they worked more than 6.5 minutes in one of the 4 15 minute periods of an hour, it would show as .15, .30, .45, or 1+.00? If they worked less than 15 minutes in a 15 minute period, it would round down to the lower 15 minute period? In you question, I do not see where in your sample output you get the 9, or where employee 1 and 2 worked 9 minutes Your sample data and output don't match up.

Comment: In your example, employee 1 worked almost 6 hours, there is no employee 2, but there is an employee 3. **Please edit your question** and show example output for the data shown. Also explain how the output is calculated.

Comment: I explained how the output was calculated in the last paragraph. In the 15 minute interval starting at 10:00:00, so 10:00:00-10:15:00, employee 1 worked 3 minutes and employee 3 worked 6 minutes for a total of 9 minutes worked during that period. It seems that I need to get the timestamp from somewhere else however. Name is arbitrary. I will update the table to show full clarity.

Comment: Unless you want to create a table that contains one row for every 15 minute period in a day, IOW just the time part, this would be better done outside MySQL in a language such as PHP (or whatever language your choose). BTW, Emp 1 worked 6 min in the first time period, and Emp 3 worked 3 minutes. The part you left out in your question was that you wanted the output to be for each 15 minute period of the day. Thanks for clarifying that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `MySQL 8.0`, you can use the `CTE` feature as follows

```
WITH cte (timeStamp) AS
(
  SELECT "2018-05-31 00:00:00"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 15, timeStamp) 
  WHERE timeStamp < 2018-06-01 00:00:00
)
SELECT timeStamp FROM cte;

SELECT cte.time, 
sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, punch.time, 
                  TIMESTAMPAD(MINUTE, 15, cte.timeStamp))) as labour_hours, 
punch.location 
FROM cte LEFT OUTER JOIN punch ON punch.time >=cte.timeStamp 
AND punch.time < TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 15, cte.timeStamp)
GROUP BY punch.location, cte.timeStamp
```

If you are using an older version of `MySQL`, you need to create a `stored procedure` that generates the timestamps with 15 minute intervals.

Comment: I am using 5.7. Is it possible maybe to join a table that has the 15 minute intervals? I do have one in the database that is 15 min intervals then use the last select query you provided to get the labor hours?